# Vue.js component not updating

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, reactive-programming

I have a Vue component that uses a boolean variable imported from another file, but no matter what I do this doesn't seem to update when the variable changes.

The variable really is updated, I confirmed it by logging it to the console with setInterval.

I thought in Vue 3 this is supposed to work, nevertheless it doesn't work either when using ref() or adding watch().

```js
<script>
import * as NetworkManager from "@/lib/network-manager";
import MainMenu from "@/components/main-menu/main-menu.vue";
import GameView from "@/components/game/game-view.vue";

export default {
    name: "App",
    components: {
        MainMenu,
        GameView,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            NetworkManager,
        };
    },
};
</script>

<template>
    <p>{{ NetworkManager.connected }}</p>
    <game-view v-if="NetworkManager.connected" />
    <main-menu v-else />
</template>
```

Comment: If the imported file does not use Vue’s reactivity system (https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-in-depth.html) it won’t work out of the box. Did you write the imported file yourself? What is the purpose of it?

Comment: @Tolbxela Your answer is confirming the OP’s problem, but is not providing a solution. Which is understandable, because that probably lies in modifying the library and the OP is not providing the purpose and code for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `NetworkManager` object becomes reactive, but you have to update the properties from `Vue`. Otherwise. `Vue` cannot detect changes. Check the playground below.

The correct ways would be:

1. add the `Vue` reactivity using Compositions API inside the `lib/network-manager` library
2. update the `NetworkManager` only from Vue routines
3. Use a Custom or `Vuex/Pinia` Storage

```js
const { createApp } = Vue

const MyObj = { counter: 0 }

function add() {
  MyObj.counter++;
  console.log(MyObj.counter)
}

const App = {
   data() {
      return {    
          MyObj
       } 
   },
   methods: {
      add() {
        this.MyObj.counter++;
        console.log(this.MyObj.counter)
      }
   }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
MyObj: {{MyObj.counter}}<br/>
<button onclick="add()">+1</button> outside Vue<br/>
<button @click="add()">+1</button> inside Vue<br/>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```